# Could not find the redis data after restart of server

Tags: redis

The data present is redis vanishes once after restarting the server.Till yesterday it was proper.Suddenly it happens today.No changes in configuration is done so far.All settings were default setting only.

**UPDATE :**
All the updates are reflected in redis client only for that session.Once restart i went to the old value itself.

**FIGURED THE MISTAKE :**

Unfortunately i am new to redis. So i am not aware of persistence in redis. I made `bgsave` 
to achieve and also i know about **Snapshotting**

Comment: Sorry for stupid question !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to clarify what you are saying is unexpected.

By

> All the updates are reflected in redis client only for that session.
>   Once restart it went to the old value itself.

do you mean to say you restart the client or the server? Does the data disappear from the server of from the client? Where is the "old value" coming from?

Now on to how to get more information as to what may be the problem and address the case of data disappearing from the *server* on a server restart.

With the limited info available this sounds like the data was not persisted to disk. There can be several causes.

Open a redis-cli session to the Redis instance (`redis-cli` if on the server itself, otherwise you'll need to pass host and port to it).

Next run the command `info persistence`. This will tell you/us if there is a problem when Redis tries to write the data to the filesystem. If the status of the last save is no "ok", your process is unable to write the dump file in (by default) /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb. In this scenario I'd expect a permission issue.Failing that it could be a disk space issue.

Assuming no space issues, check the permissions on the directory /var/lib/redis and the files therein. If they don't match the user running the redis-server you will need to correct them via `chown -R redisuser:redisgroup /var/lib/redis` where redisuser and redisgroup match the user running the redis-server. Once this is done, go back in/to the CLI and issue `BGSAVE`. Wait a few seconds and rerun the `info persistence` command to validate you are able to save.

If it still fails I'd suggest running the redis-server in a terminal to see the output, and rerun a save so you can see what errors are being reported. if you have this being logged, then check the logs for the error(s).

If the save is successful the data is being stored by the server and will survive a restart on the server side. If this is the case and the data is "disappearing" from the client when the client restarts we will need to see the code from the client to determine exactly what it is doing.

Cheers,
Bill

Comment: Thank you bill!! . I am pretty new to redis and i failed to read certain info regarding this..